# How do I use group by in LINQ?

Tags: c#

How do I use group by in LINQ?
 I want to group by tow filed of table in C# by linq.

Comment: can you provide some code sample?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869001/linq-group-by-multiple-fields-syntax-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query =
    from t in db.tableName    
    group t by new { t.column1, t.column2 } into g
    select new { g.Key.column1, g.Key.column2 };
```