# C# Linq : Group By different columns of different entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have three entities ClassC, ClassS and ClassSA. I want to apply group by using LINQ.

```
using (var db = new SEntities())
{
    var result = from c in db.ClassC
    join s in db.ClassS on c.ID equals s.CID
    join sa in db.ClassSA on s.SAID equals sa.ID
    group sa by
    new { c.Type, s.Date.Year}
    into g
    select new ClassSAY { Year = g.Key.Year, CI = g.Key.CIType, Count = g.Count(sa => sa.ID)};
}
```

I want to join ClassC, ClassS and ClassSA; group by two different properties of two different classes and store some part of result in another class's properties. I have searched by found group by only one class' properties.

It's giving error:

1. Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<SG.DAL.SA,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'bool'

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869001/linq-group-by-multiple-fields-syntax-help

Comment: http://www.manojn.com/blog/post/Group-by-Multiple-Columns-using-Anonymous-Types-in-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use like

```
Count = g.Count()
```

instead of

```
Count = g.Count(sa => sa.ID)
```