# Merging 2 or more column from file and obtaining the result in c#

Tags: c#

My file is:

```
outlook temperature Humidity Windy PlayTennis 

sunny hot high false N

sunny hot high true N

overcast hot high false P

rain mild high false P

rain cool normal false P
```

I found out unique elements from file as:

```
element:occurence

suny :2 

overcast:1 

rain:2

mild:1

cool:1

hot :4

normal:1

high:2

false:4

true:1 

n:2

p:3
```

Then I removed elements whose occurrence was less than 1.

as output came as:

```
suny : 2
rain: 2
hot :3
high:4
false:4
n:2 
p:3
```

Now I want output as (from the first output, it should loop with every other element to make a set of two frequent set)

```
element:occurence

sunny,hot:2
sunny,high:2
sunny,false:1
sunny,n:2
sunny,p:0
rain,hot:0
rain,high:1
rain,false:2
rain,n:0
rain,p:2
hot,high:2
hot,false:1
hot,n:2
hot,p:0
and so on..
```

Here is my code:

```
var occurences = File.ReadAllLines(file)
    .Skip(1)
    .SelectMany(l => l.Split(new []{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .GroupBy(w => w)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

foreach(var pair in occurences)
    label1.Text += String.Format("{0}: {1}\n", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

I implemented this to find the 1st frequent set.

For 2nd one what should I do?

I also need to find the third set.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by refactoring. 1) Make a class to hold the data items

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public string Outlook { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string Humidity { get; set; }
    public bool Windy { get; set; }
    public string PlayTennis { get; set; }
}
```

Then create your objects;

```
var forecasts = new List<WeatherForecast>();
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(file).Skip(1))
{
    var values = line.Split(' ');
    forecasts.Add(new WeatherForecast
                      {
                          Outlook = values[0],
                          Temperature = values[1],
                          Humidity = values[2],
                          Windy = Convert.ToBoolean(values[3]),
                          PlayTennis = values[4]
                      });
}
```

Then you might be able to figure out how you want to query your data with Linq.

For grouping help see [LINQ Group By Multiple fields -Syntax help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869001/linq-group-by-multiple-fields-syntax-help)

```
//Group by 1 key
forecasts.GroupBy(f => new { f.Outlook }, (key, group) => new { Key1 = key.Outlook, Count = group.Count() });

//Group by 2 keys
forecasts.GroupBy(f => new { f.Outlook, f.Temperature }, (key, group) => new { Key1 = key.Outlook, Key2 = key.Temperature , Count = group.Count()});

//Group by 3 keys
forecasts.GroupBy(f => new { f.Outlook, f.Temperature, f.Humidity }, (key, group) => new { Key1 = key.Outlook, Key2 = key.Temperature, Key3 = key.Humidity, Count = group.Count()});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Want output for two elements.
as i mentioned in the output.
Please suggest.

Comment: yes..the idea is perfect..
but a very silly question...to represent this value in label..i tuk,,
var forecast=forecasts.GroupBy(f => new { f.Outlook }, (key, group) => new { Key1 = key.Outlook, Count = group.Count() });

as Dump over here shows error(system.collection.generic.ienumerable does not contain definition for dump), so have removed dump.

label1.text=forecasts.tostring(); -- doesnt work...
should i take dictionary ??

Comment: @BelaKharidia Just get rid of the Dump. That is Linqpad specific.

Comment: okay..for printig values, this is not working ..
 var forecast=forecasts.GroupBy(f => new { f.Outlook }, (key, group) => new { Key1 = key.Outlook, Count = group.Count() });
 label1.text=forecasts.tostring();

Comment: You can't use ToString on the Enumerable. Try using a foreach loop over the enumerable and ToString each member using a StringBuilder.

Comment: StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();



foreach (StringBuilder values in forecast1)

{


    label1.Text = values.ToString();

    

}


somthing like this ?

Comment: @BelaKharidia `var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); foreach(var item in forecast1) { stringBuilder.AppendFormat("Key1 {0} Count {1}", item.Key1, item.Count); }` That should put you in the right direction.